# Express.js: node.js, express.js and jade in form post, doesn´t show the second page

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express

I´m new in node and express and I do a little app but it doesn´t work. I do post in page 1, and the app doesn´t show page 2. The structure and code is:

```
/
/controller/controllers.js
/node_modules/express
             /jade
             /mongoose
/view/index1.jade
     /index2.jade
     /layout.jade
app.js
package.json
```

The app.js

```
/* server */
var express = require('express')    
  , routes = require('./routes')
  , fs = require('fs');

//Create server
var app = express.createServer();

//Use controller
var controllers_path = __dirname + '/controllers'
    ,controller_files = fs.readdirSync(controllers_path);
    controller_files.forEach(function (file) {
        require(controllers_path+'/'+file)(app);
});

//Jade configuration
app.configure(function() {
    app.set('view options', { layout: false });
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + ''));
});

app.listen(3001);
console.log("listening on port %d", app.address().port);
```

The controller.js

```
module.exports = function(app, auth){

    // Get
    app.get('/test1', function(req, res){
        res.render('index.jade', {});
    });

    // Post
    app.get('/test2', function(req, res){
        res.render('index2.jade', {});
    });

};
```

The index.jade

```
extends layout
block content   
    form(method="post", action="/test2")
    p
    input(type="submit")
```

The index2.jade

```
extends layout
block content
    p Page 2
```

The layout.jade

```
h1 Test layout
block content
```

Thank you!

Comment: You don't have a route to handle post...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you don't have a POST handler for `/test2`.  In your HTML, you're specifying `method="POST"`, but in your controller, you're handling the GET method only.

You want to change it to this:

```
// Post
app.post('/test2', function(req, res){
    res.render('index2.jade', {});
});
```

Incidentally, if you want to handle all request types, you can can use `app.all`, and then decide what to do based on the method type:

```
app.all('/test2', function(req, res){
    if(req.method==='GET'){
        // one response for GET requests
    } if(req.method==='POST'){
        // another response for POST requests
    } else {
        // catch all...PUT, DELETE, etc.
    }
});
```

Comment: I have changed it, and when is push the button the app do nothing. I put a log in app.post..... and show it by console.

Comment: Are you saying the `console.log` for the POST handler DOES or DOESN'T happen on the server?

Comment: Excuse me, doesn´t show the log, doesn´t enter in app.post('/test2', function(req, res)

Comment: Try linking in the logger, and see what's going on.  `app.use(express.logger('dev'));`

Comment: It doesn't show anything, you mean?  It must at least log a GET for `/test1`, right?